# What is wrong with this code that is causing Syntax Error in PostgreSQL 9.3

Tags: sql, postgresql, lateral

Below is a piece of SQL code I wrote. I want to merge two records in to one record where the first record domain is shown as "From source" and the second record's domain become "To Domain". There will be more filtering I need to do but why is this simple statement not working?

I get an error "Syntax error at end of input"

```
*SELECT 
   "ID" , "Time",  "Source Domain", "To Domain" From
   (SELECT "RecordID" As "ID","UTCTimestamp" As "Time","Domain" As "Source Domain" FROM public."Traffic - Mobile")T1
   Inner Join Lateral
   (SELECT "Domain" As "To Domain" FROM public."Traffic - Mobile" where "RespondentID"="T1"."RespondentID" )T2*
```

Thanks in advance

PostgreSQL version 9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating this. A simple self join of the table is enough. You don't need a derived table to rename a column

```
SELECT "ID", "Time", t1."Domain" as "Source Domain", t2."Domain" as "To Domain" 
from public."Traffic - Mobile" as t1
  join public."Traffic - Mobile" as t2 on t2."RespondentID" = t1."RespondentID";
```

Comment: I am getting the following error. This is useful. What will i miss from lateral join?

ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "T1"
SQL state: 42P01

Comment: @user2315860: sorry, copy & paste error. (In general you should avoid quoted identifiers like the plague)

Answer (score 0):

I think you still need an `ON` clause since it's an `INNER JOIN`. If you didn't want to specify an `ON` clause, I think you could use `CROSS JOIN` instead.

E.g.

```
SELECT 
   "ID" , "Time",  "Source Domain", "To Domain" From
   (SELECT "RecordID" As "ID","UTCTimestamp" As "Time","Domain" As "Source Domain"
          FROM public."Traffic - Mobile")T1
   Inner Join Lateral
   (SELECT "Domain" As "To Domain" FROM public."Traffic - Mobile"
           where "RespondentID"="T1"."RespondentID" )T2
    ON true
```

Comment: I'm getting  this error 

ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "T1"
SQL state: 42P01